# views_datasource module problem with encoding

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I installed [views_datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module to get json output of a view. There is a content type in my website called `translations` and English, Arabic and Persian texts are saved in there. This module works well but it has problem with encoding the Persian and Arabic texts. it outputs the json like this:

[image]

How do I can solve this problem.

---

UPDATE:

The views admin UI generates the true output as this picture shows

[image]

But when I visit the page path through browser I see the first picture

Comment: Those are valid unicode chars, what's the problem?

Comment: I updated the question. The Persian and Arabic characters are displayed well in the views admin UI  but when I go to the page path of the view, it shows the picture. (I also should let you know that I didn't test it by android app yet)

Comment: I don't think you're getting me - they're exactly the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771938/any-way-to-return-php-json-encode-with-encode-utf-8-and-not-unicode. If you want non-unicode char representations for vanity or some other reason you'll probably need to patch `drupal_json_encode()` and make use of [`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php). It's a lot more about PHP than it is about Drupal, this is default behaviour for the language

Comment: Won't this cause any problem with the android application that will receive the text?

Comment: _What_ problem? I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: I was just confusing why the result of the json output in the views admin UI and the direct link of views page path are different and I was going to to make sure that the android application will get the right text; and you said `they're exactly the same thing`.

Comment: Ah ok - it's just formatted in the ui, that's all. You're seeing a slightly different representation of the same data

Comment: @Clive The `node` is Top-level child object for every content, Is there anyway to change this? for example replace the `node` with node ID of content?